# Where to put business logic in a Java EE enterprise application

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, business-logic

When creating an enterprise Java EE application, part of the business logic like messaging (MDBs) has to be put inside the EJB module. However, there are some EJBs which can be placed inside either the EJB module or the web module. I know that separating modules allows the web tier and the business tier to be deployed in different machines. Thus, I would place my `@Stateful` shopping cart EJB in the web module. However, I cannot think of a standard criteria which can be applied to every piece of business logic, deciding where to put the EJBs enclosing them. Is there a guideline, standard or recommended practice for this?

Comment: Could you name some of these 'piece[s] of business logic'?

Comment: - Processing reports of an external application received via messaging, simultaneously pushing them to web interfaces (for real-time monitoring via the web interface) and saving results to a database.

- The shopping cart example I mentioned in the question, as well as processing a customer order of which details are gathered from web-based interfaces.

- Generating graphics and images based on user content.

- Generating queries on some NoSQL data source based on user-provided parameters, running the queries and process the results to be shown in a meaningful way.

These are just samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've found out so far.

The EJB module is supposed to enclose the core of the business logic for a large enterprise application. Web module, on the other hand, encloses a full-fledged web application which is supposed to take advantage of the business engine provided by the EJB module. Usually these modules are distributed among different servers for larger applications, and there are client applications (a Swing/JFX desktop application for instance) other than the web application which need to consume services provided by the core business logic which resides in EJB modules.

In other words, one would put the business logic in a separate EJB module if:

1. It is meant to be used by multiple web or desktop applications, or
2. Scaling considerations may force the core business logic to be handled by separate servers

In other cases, one may put his EJBs inside the web module and package the whole thing as a WAR file.

Comment: Indeed, but realize it's trivial to move EJB beans from a package in the web module to their own EJB module. You can thus start with such simple package and then move to a module if your app is a big enough or when you need to deploy the business layer seperately.

Comment: The last part of your findings, EJB can be put inside WAR, if EJB modules exists then it is deployed using EAR right? WAR and EJB in EAR? Regards

Comment: Yes. An EAR (enterprise application) consists of a number of WARs (web modules) and a number of JARs (ejb modules). This is appropriate when your enterprise app is designed to be distributed among several servers (several modules) but you want all your modules to be deployed on a single server in a specific case. However, if it's unlikely that you want to distribute the modules among different servers, you may simply put all of the EJBs in a WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your last sentence, that is exactly what I'd propose: Use the WAR packaging for JEE6 applications, as you won't need EARs for most cases.

If you need to share business logic between several applications, then you can deploy that as a separate module. But usually such a thing is not necessary for scaling reasons, since you can as well dimension the application server running your WAR accordingly.